# How to build angular 8 with ngx-quill?

Tags: angular, ngx-quill

> ERROR in Directive QuillEditorBase in C:/Users/sijaw/Documents/Projects/Student Portal/staff-portal-latest/staff-portal/node_modules/ngx-quill/ngx-quill.d.ts has no selector, please add it!
>
> Cannot determine the module for class QuillEditorBase in C:/Users/sijaw/Documents/Projects/Student Portal/staff-portal-latest/staff-portal/node_modules/ngx-quill/ngx-quill.d.ts! Add QuillEd
> itorBase to the NgModule to fix it.

Comment: Okay, those are errors.  But how did you get there?  Edit your question to include code and/or steps on what you've built so far.

Comment: I got the same error. It looks like it has something to do with ngx-quill version.